# Xcode instruments hosed with iOS 6.1.2 upgrade?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, profile

Just made the mistake of upgrading my iPhone (which also doubles as my development device) to iOS 6.1.2; Xcode will run my development work on the phone but I'm trying to profile memory usage and the instruments screen doesn't work (appears but won't run). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer for you after going through this for a while. What you do not see in Instruments is some activity which is going on in the background. Open up Xcode and then the Organizer to see the devices. Select the one you want to target and you will see it is preparing the device. Once it is completed see Instruments again. You may need to restart Instruments before the device is made available.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK, after restarting a bunch of times, no new downloads, it's started working again. I know XCode less than I think.